# Why do these javascript form calculations not work in Safari and Firefox but they do in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am running the following code:  The first two little functions work because I am using the jquery calculate plugin... the last 3 fail in Firefox and Safari but work in Chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("input[id^='balance']").sum("keyup", "#totalbalance");
    $("input[id^='payment']").sum("keyup", "#totalpayment");

    $('input.ltv1, input.ltv2').click(function() {
        var ltv1 = parseFloat($('.ltv1').val()||"0");
        var ltv2 = parseFloat($('.ltv2').val()||"0");
        result = ltv2/ltv1;
        total = parseInt(result);
        $('.ltv').text(total);
    }); 

    $('input.bal1, input.bal2, input.bal3, input.ltv2').change(function() {
        var bal1 = parseFloat($('.bal1').val() || "0");
        var bal2 = parseFloat($('.bal2').val() || "0");
        var bal3 = parseFloat($('.bal3').val() || "0");
        var bal = bal1 + bal2 + bal3
        var hv = parseFloat($('.ltv2').val() || "0");
        result = bal / hv;
        total = parseInt(result);
    $('.clv').text(total);
    });

    $('input.bal1, input.bal2, input.bal3, input.income').change(function() {
        var bal1 = parseFloat($('.bal1').val() || "0");
        var bal2 = parseFloat($('.bal2').val() || "0");
        var bal3 = parseFloat($('.bal3').val() || "0");
        var bal = bal1 + bal2 + bal3
        var income = parseFloat($('.income').val() || "0");
        result = bal / income;
        total = parseInt(result);
        $('.dti').text(total);
    });

});

</script>
```

I am not the best at javascript so I have pieced this together...

Anyway the site is http://settlementprep.com/pre-qual/homeowner/ and the little boxes show the different calculations:  Loan to Value and Combined Loan to Mortgage don't work..

Anyone have a clue?

thanks

Comment: Also, your form has like fifty textboxes on it. Can you tell us which ones to fill out to trigger the error?

Comment: Why are you doing this: `total = parseInt(result);` when result is already a number?  Do you mean to be doing `Math.round()` or `Math.floor()` to convert a decimal to an integer?  Also, you should usually never use `parseInt()` without specifying the radix because it will guess.

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Do you get an error message in the console, or...? By the way, it doesn't work in Chrome either: when I followed your link and typed some numbers I got "NaN" coming up in the bottom right field. (Also, you seem to be using classes where you should use ids.)

Comment: Also get several PHP errors when I just submit. Also this is wrong:  `<label for="1st_balance">Balance:*</label>

                    <input name="1st_balance" id="balance" class="ltv1 bal1" />`

label should be for an ID and not a NAME

Please give all your fields a unique ID and use that in the calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript, I see this:

```
$('.ltv').text(total);
```

But, in your page, I don't see any object with a `class="ltv"`.  I see this HTML:

```
<p id="ltv"></p>
```

which would imply your javascript code should be this instead:

```
$('#ltv').text(total);
```

The same appears to be true for `.clv`.  Code and HTML don't match.

FYI, I also see undeclared global variables like `result` and `total`.  These should be local variables (with `var` in front of their first use to make them local variables).